# UIAlertView show multiple message

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

how can i show multiple messages in my alertView from different variables?

Comment: what do you mean by multiple???Please explain your question....

Comment: What you mean saying multiple messages ???

Comment: like different values and with different titles.Like played time :30;Score :90%.And show then in different line.Is it clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the desired `NSString` from your multiple variables, e.g.:

```
NSString *foo;
NSString *bar;
NSString *baz;
// ... set values for foo, bar and baz ...
NSString *myMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", foo, bar, baz];
```

Then set your alert view to use the composite message `myMessage`:

```
NSString *myTitle = @"xyz";
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                       initWithTitle: myTitle
                       message: myMessage
                       delegate: nil
                       cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: I want to show titles and values in multiple lines.For example...total time played:30,total score :90...i have calculated values now just need to show them with corresponding titles with.You got the idea now?

Comment: You can add newline characters (`\n`) to the message string, in order to have "multiple lines": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: thanks..it's working..i wish if i could make a dynamic AlertViewController...any idea how to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by dynamic. Maybe you could ask a second, separate question and describe in more detail what you mean.

Comment: ok..leave it.. can you tell me something...how can i make the titleText left Alight in my alertView?

Comment: You can't, at least not directly. Apple doesn't make it possible to do with their `UIAlertView` class. You could leave the title blank and pour in a custom `UIView` with `UILabel` elements positioned with the dimensions you want, but that's well beyond the scope of what would go into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string1=@"total time played:30\n";
    NSString *string2=@"total score :90\n";
    NSString *string3=@"19/2/20010 12:00:77\n";
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",string1,string2,string3];
    UIAlertView *progressAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:string delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [progressAlert show];
    [progressAlert release];
```

Comment: i wan to show.time,score,correctAns,wrongAns etc after the game Finishes.So i need to show them with multiline and with corresponding values.Please tell me how can i do that with your approach

Comment: see my edited answer in this way you can show your text in seperate lines

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str1=@"Message 1.";
NSString *str2= @"Message 2.";
NSString *str3 = @"Message 3";


NSString *msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@",str1,str2,str3];


FreeCoinsCustomAlert* alert = [[FreeCoinsCustomAlert alloc] initWithTitle:msg
                                                                  message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to flesh out your question a bit more, but working from my understanding of your question, you should just be able to use the

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
```

UIAlertView constructor. Then just concatenate your variables into a single `NSString` object and pass it as the `(NSString*)message`. The

```
+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...
```

factory method makes this trivial. I would recommend [reading your options with NSString in the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).